# Disabling or Hiding a React component when another component is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router, react-hooks

I'm learning React and atm i'm making a crud App for Employee Data. Now the problem I'm having is that when i click on **Add New button** or **Update button** my component loads for respective features but my old component which is my Table of Data for all my employees stays open along with the new component. I want my Table of data to be disabled or hidden until my New Employee is added or old employee is updated on submission but i'm unable to do that... I made the **AddNew.js** for adding new employees, **UpdateMember.js** for updating old employees and then imported these components in my **Table.js** file which is then **returned** in the **App.js** component

The update component loads right on the spot of the update button itself which is another problem for me right now.

[image]

almost same is happening with Update even worse with this one

[image]

**AddNew.js**

```
 function AddNew() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(null);
  const [Name, setName] = useState("");
  const [Department, setDepartment] = useState("");
  const [Salary, setSalary] = useState("");

  const Data = {
    name: Name,
    department: Department,
    salary: Salary,
  };
  const PostData = () => (event) => {
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    // header.append("Accept", "application/json");
    //
    return (
      fetch(PostUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: header,
        body: JSON.stringify(Data),
      })
        ///
        .then(() => {
          fetch(BaseUrl, { method: "GET", headers: header })
            //
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
              setList(result);
            });
        })
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={PostData}>
        <h2>Add New Members</h2>
        <span>* All fields are required</span>
        <div className="outerDiv">
          <div className="innerDiv">
            <input
              type="text"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Name"
              onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="innerDiv">
            <input
              type="text"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="Department"
              placeholder="Department"
              onChange={(event) => setDepartment(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="innerDiv">
            <input
              type="text"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="Salary"
              placeholder="Salary"
              onChange={(event) => setSalary(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AddNew;
```

**UpdateMember.js**

```
  const UpdateRow = () => (event) => {
    const PutData = {
      name: Name,
      department: Department,
      salary: Salary,
    };
    console.log("Update Clicked");
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    header.append("Accept", "application/json");

    fetch(PutUrl, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: header,
      body: JSON.stringify(PutData),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .then(() => {
        fetch(BaseUrl, { method: "GET", headers: header })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => {
            setList(result);
          });
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={UpdateRow}>
        <span className="text">* All fields are required</span>

        <hr />
        <div>
          <h2>Update Information</h2>

          <div className="outerDiv">
            <div className="innerDiv">
              <input
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="innerDiv">
              <input
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                name="Department"
                placeholder="Department"
                onChange={(event) => setDepartment(event.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="innerDiv">
              <input
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                name="Salary"
                placeholder="Salary"
                onChange={(event) => setSalary(event.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <button
              style={{ float: "right" }}
              className="button btn-warning"
              type="submit"
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default UpdateMember;
```

**Table.js**

```
function Table() {
  //
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    getList().then((items) => {
      if (mounted) {
        setList(items);
      }
    });
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);
  //
  const DeleteRow = (id) => (event) => {
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    header.append("Accept", "application/json");

    return fetch(DeleteUrl + id, { method: "DELETE", headers: header }).then(
      () => {
        fetch(BaseUrl, { method: "GET", headers: header })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            setList(result);
          });
      }
    );
  };
  //
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Employees Data</h1>
      <Router>
        <Link to="/Addnew" target="_blank">
          <button
            style={{ float: "right" }}
            className="button  btn-primary LinkButton"
          >
            Add New
          </button>
        </Link>
        <Route path="/AddNew">
          <AddNew />
        </Route>
      </Router>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>
                <center>{item.id}</center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>{item.name}</center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>{item.department}</center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>{item.salary}</center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <button
                    // key={item.id}
                    className="button btn-danger"
                    onClick={DeleteRow(item.id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <Router>
                    <Link to="/UpdateMember">
                      <button className="button btn-warning LinkButton">
                        Update
                      </button>
                    </Link>
                    <Switch>
                      <Route path="/UpdateMember">
                        <UpdateMember id={item.id} />
                      </Route>
                    </Switch>
                  </Router>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Table;
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    
    <Table />
  );

}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new variable called isLoading which will be set to true when you start a fetch and false after the fetch has finished. Then after that you can use it to check if isLoading is true, if it is true, do not show the table (conditional rendering)

And another suggestion would be creating a spinner to show when loading is true and hide when it is false, so that the user will know that it is loading.

Comment: Yes i also did the same way and it is working

Answer (score 1):

I think that some conditional rendering could help you out with the problem.

Check it out [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).